# Cannot feed value of shape (32, 1, 3) for Tensor u'/X:0', which has shape '(?, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, tflearn

I want to create a reinforcement project, but I struggle with some problems.

I have a class for my neural network. Consisting of one Input Layer, two Hidden Layer and one output-Layer. It is created with tflearn.

```
class Network():
    self.inputs, self.outputs = self.createNetwork()
    [...]
    def createNetwork(self):

        # Input-Layer
        inputs = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3])

        # Hidden-Layer L1
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(inputs, 400, activation='relu')                                   

        # Hidden Layer L2
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 300, activation='relu')                                   

        # Final layer weights are init to Uniform[-3e-3, 3e-3]
        weight_init_final = tflearn.initializations.uniform(minval=-0.003, maxval=0.003)
        output = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='tanh', weights_init=weight_init_final)

        return inputs, output
```

And the method for predicting a value

```
def predict(self, inputs):
   return self.sess.run(self.outputs, feed_dict={
   self.inputs: inputs
   })
```

I train with a batch size of 32 and want to predict a value.

```
network.predict(test_batch)
```

Sadly I get an error
'Cannot feed value of shape (32, 1, 3) for Tensor u'/X:0', which has shape '(?, 3)'
test_batch.shape results in (32, 1, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input layer is expecting a shape of (?,3)  --> `inputs = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 3])`
The input_shape should be `(None, 1, 3)` to match the shape of your data.

Comment: I'm so stupid... Didnt realize that I have 3 dimensions, when two are enough. Shape (32, 3) solved the problem.